# What is the best way to implement an application that saves data for customized products with different kinds of data fields?

Tags: c#, database, database-design, database-schema

Suppose we have a database with two tables `Product` and `ProductField`. Table `ProductField` contains several fields related to each Product in the `Product` table. So For one product it's Id repeats several times in `ProductField`. That's a nice schema for saving customized products with several different fields for each one.

[image: Basic solution]

But there is a problem with this naive solution. For example in the above image you can see that product fields have different types, string for Name and numerical value for Price field. Therefore we have to save the type of each field, somewhere in our application. I thought it would be  good idea to save this types in another table as follows:

[image: Field Types]

This solves the problem of unknown types. But there still exist type casting problem. Because we still need to save all values in the field value of the first table which is a string column. So we have to cast the values to the required type in our application. This is the code we need:

```
        // string fieldType retrieved from database
        // string fieldValue retrieved from database
        if (fieldType == "string")
        {
            // do something with fieldValue
        }
        else if (fieldType == "int")
        {
            // do something with int.Parse(fieldValue)
        }
        .
        .
```

The third solution is to use one table for each field type. The following picture illustrates the solution I have in my mind.

[image: One table for each field type]

As you can see one disadvantage of this solution is that you can not create new field types straightforward. You have to create new tables and change database schema in run time if you want to add new field types.
**But one advantage of this solution is that you do not need to cast the string value to int or double or whatever the real format of the saved value is.** 
*What do you think about the third solution? Does it make sense?*

Comment: how would you know the table to which your product gets inserted to?

Comment: Have you tried doing retrieval or reporting using these data structures?  With any of them, I expect it to be a nightmare.  Think ahead to what you are going to do with the data.

Comment: @Ayoubi We can join the tables StringTbl and IntTbl. Then search for the desired productId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you really *really* need to have one table that caters for different product types with different characteristics, a simple way to go would be to have 3 tables:

- header table that includes all products (product id is a primary key)
- table for quantifiable fields (floats) with N rows per product (price, size, percentile, ...)
- table for un-quantifiable fields (varchar) with N rows per product (description, warnings, ...)

something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can we say that your approach is actually a special case of the third solution? The theory is the same but in implementation you limited the number of field types to quantifiable and un-quantifiable.

Comment: @a.toraby Indeed it is, keep in mind the header table difference that groups all products (regardless of their characteristics), which is where you'll go when you need to query products.